# Literature on multinomial logistic regression with random effects

Tags: r, mixed-model, references, multinomial-logit

The title pretty much says it all: I am looking for a good reference to understand multinomial logistic regression with random effects and the estimation of such models. Furthermore, I am also looking for a way to implement such models in R.

Comment: for R, check out `mlogit`, `nmlogit`, or `nnet.` Not sure which have RE capability though.

Comment: I  have a 2002 edition of this book by Agresti that touches on the more intellectual aspects in Chs 13 and 14. An Introduction to Categorical Data Analysis by Alan Agresti, looks like the 2012 edition has similar structure but probably more up to date: https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Categorical+Data+Analysis%2C+3rd+Edition-p-9780470463635